# Is mockito changing the objects?

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I have the following structure

```
public class A{...}

public class B extends A{
    private C cObject;
    private Object otherValue;

    B(){
       cObject = new C(this);
    }
}

public class C{
    private B bObject;

    C(B bObject){
       this.bObject = bObject;
    }
}
```

I want to test a method of the class B. I am using mockito because I need to mock another method of B in order to test the method I want to test. So In my test I declare the B object as `@Spy`, then I call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` and finally I mock the method using `doReturn().when().method();`

Now I run the test and it fails. My surprise comes when I debug it and I realize that when I am in the object B, the value of the field `otherValue` is for example `X` but when I am in C, the value of `this.bObject.otherValue` is not `X` but `null`.

Since I've created the object C within B with `new C(this);`, shouldn't both B and C.bObject be the same object and contain therefore the same values?

**NOTE**: I've also tried it without spying the object and mocking the method and it works, so the real question is:

Does Mockito replace my object with another object when I spy it? And in that case, what can I do to make it work?

**EDIT** an easier explanation could be: I want to test an object B, this object B creates an instance of an object C passing itself (this) as parameter. I need to Spy the object B so I create in my test an instance of B and then call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`. Are both objects (the one in the test and the one in the instance of C) after this calling still the same object or mockito replaced it with a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `B` instance will be constructed before being spied, so the reference that `C` receives is the *actual* `B` object and not the spied instance.

You're adding behaviour to the spied instance which is indeed a different object to the one that `C.bObject` has, so the behaviour is not applied. Similarly setting `b.otherValue` will not result on `b.cObject.bObject.otherValue` being set.

You can see that these are different objects - assuming a default `toString` is present:

```
final B b = Mockito.spy(new B());

System.out.println("spied: " + b);
System.out.println("b.cObject.bObject: " + b.cObject.bObject);
```

It should produce something along the lines of:

```
spied: B$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$999ce15d@7a187814
b.cObject.bObject: B@5c73a7ab
```

Perhaps you could use reflection to set `b.cObject.bObject` field to the spied instance? For example:

```
final Field f = C.class.getDeclaredField("bObject");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(b.cObject, b);
```

Comment: ´spied: B$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$999ce15d@7a187814´ that's the point. I saw it in the watch section of Eclipse. Is there any work around for this situation?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really sure what to suggest - I would normally say pass in the spied object but it's not that easy in this case. Is there no way of breaking the circular reference?

Comment: there's actually no way to break it because it is legacy code, so I just need a way to handle it. And I cannot pass the mocked object after creating it because there is no 'set' method for it...

Comment: @iberbeu I thought that might be so. Have you thought about using reflection to inject the spied instance? See my updated answer - not sure if that would be possible for your code though.

Comment: reflection was my last option but I think it is what I need... thanks for your answer, i'll try it

Comment: Ok, that doesn't seem to be possible as well. For injecting the spied instance I have to do reflection on the spied instance itself and since it has been spied it is not a normal object anymore and the fields don't have the same names. Another idea?